# Curious behaviour with browser with single quote and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a page with a link like:

```
  <%= link_to_function(
        'my function',
        "my_js_method('#{escape_javascript(
          t('.wanna',
            :name => h(name)
          ))
         }', this)",
      ) %>
```

The generated code with a name `"<foo'bar>"` is :

```
<a href="#" onclick="my_js_method('Wanna <foo'bar> ?', this); return false;">my_function</a>
```

You will notice the single quote in the middle of the `onclick` attribute.

The curious think is when I execute these lines in the rails console :

```
>> helper.send(:html_escape, "<foo'bar>")
=> "&lt;foo&#39;bar&gt;"

>> helper.send(:escape_javascript, helper.send(:html_escape, "<foo'bar>"))
=> "&lt;foo&#39;bar&gt;"
```

So is my browser (Chromium) interpreting the `&#39;`, `&lt;` and `&gt;` in the reading HTML process?

How to ignore this transformation; to keep the escaped characters?

Comment: `onclick="my_js_method('Wanna <foo\'bar> ?', this); return false;"` ???

Comment: @A.Wolff, Yes, that's the result I want, but I need to escape the html of the name too...